# Insert in MySql database DataGrid Values

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I want to add to mysql database values which i entered in datagrid view.

[image]

To delete currently selected ID i use this code.

```
       Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        SqlConn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "delete from  where id='" & DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index & "'"
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, SqlConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Data deleted")
        ucitaj()
        SqlConn.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

But how to add directly from data grid view. I enter the values on the empty field and when i click add i want to add it . I know to add in mysql database i need to use this query

```
query = "insert into base (id, Username, password, Link) values(Which ones ?)"
```

Comment: since your DGV is databound you cannot add record directly .. You can add with your query and refresh your DGV ..

Comment: @matzone i want to add it with query but the values which i entered into DGV

Comment: but you cannot add new row in your DGV ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just quick and dirty. in fact you should do this parameterized

you just have to select it so currentrow is not nothing

```
    If Not DataGridView1.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
        Dim id As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("ID").Value
        Dim username As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("username").Value
        Dim pw As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("password").Value
        Dim link As String = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Link").Value

        Dim sqlstr As String = "insert into base (id, Username, password, Link) values(" & id & "," & username & "," & pw & "," & link & ")"
        'your code
    End If
```